# What is the flaw in both of my approaches to this limit?

Tags: limits

I have been solving a 3D limit problem: $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}-1}$$which apparently, is $2$.  However, I cannot find the flaw in my approach.  Here it goes:
$$\mathrm{Let \space y=mx} \\\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+m^2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+m^2x^2+1}-1}= \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2(1+m^2)}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}-1}=\frac{0}{0} \\ \mathrm{Apply \space L'Hôpital's \space rule}\\ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x(1+m^2)}{(\frac{2x}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}})}$$
I've solved this two different ways and I keep getting the answer as $(1+m^2)$.  The *Student Solutions Manual*, alas, says the answer it $2$.  Just in case my mistake lies somewhere after this step, even though I got the same answer solving it two different ways after this point I'll give you one of my methods, the shorter of the two:
$$...\space=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{2x(1+m^2)\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{2x}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{(1+m^2)\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{1}=(1+m^2)$$
No idea how to get to $2$ here.  Also, am I abusing notation by leaving the bounds of the limits in terms of $(x,y)$ rather than reducing it to $x$ when I have let $y$ be equal to some terms of $x$?

Comment: After you plug in $y=mx$, the very next step you incorrectly simplify the denominator from $\sqrt{x^2+m^2x^2+1}-1$ to $\sqrt{2x^2+1}-1$.

Comment: Stupid Mistakes: Bane of my life.

Comment: you ain't the only one :)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Use polar coordinates, and rationalize the denominator. (When one sees $x^2+y^2$, which is often, switching to polar coordinates is usually the right approach.)

In this case, we do not even have to use polar coordinates, rationalizing the denominator is enough.

**Remark:** Using $y=mx$ is probably not a good start, since given that $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ gives us no useful information about their **ratio**.

Comment: An addendum to the last comment: it is possible in theory for $\lim_{x\to0} f(x,mx) = c$ for every $m$, yet $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)$ to not exist. Perhaps $\lim_{x\to0} f(x,x^2) = -c$, for example. (I see this is what @sahimat is saying in his/her answer.)

Answer (score 4):

Rationalize the denominator:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}-1}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}-1}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}+1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}+1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}=\frac{(x^2+y^2)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}+1)}{(x^2+y^2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}+1)-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}=\frac{(x^2+y^2)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}+1)}{x^2+y^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}+1 \, .
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

All of these answers are good, I personally always rationalize the denominator whenever I see something like that as a first try.

You should also remember that you cannot prove a limit exists by using the approach method. You can show a limit does NOT exist by showing it does not yield the same result from 2 different approaches (be that different, lines, parabolas, trig fns etc).

Showing a limit exists you'll want to: 1. manipulate it using algebra (like rationalizing the denominator here), 2. using polar/spherical coordinates (in the case of R2 or R3) and showing as the radius goes to 0, or 3. squeeze theorem, which is easiest when you're given something going to (**0**), where you can use the property that the if the limit of the absolute value of a function goes to 0, then the function itself will also go to 0 (again, used for manipulating squeeze theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Try using polar coordinates:

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\implies\;\;\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}-1}\rightarrow\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{r^2+1}-1}=\frac{r^2\left(\sqrt{r^2+1}+1\right)}{r^2}=$$

$$=\sqrt{r^2+1}+1\xrightarrow[r\to 0^+]{}2$$

Answer (score 2):

If you set $\ x=\rho\cos(\theta), y=\rho\sin(\theta)$ , you have:
$$\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{\rho^2}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}-1}= \lim_{\rho\to0} \frac{\rho^2}{1+\frac{\rho^2}{2}+o(\rho^2)-1}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}=2 $$

Where I used the fact that $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}+o(x)$ , for $\ x\to0$